# How to check for a match on a whole word in javascript

Tags: javascript, pentaho, kettle

I am trying to perform a javascript function in pentaho kettle.
I have:

```
var y;
y= ['ab', 'f', 'c'].indexOf('b')
```

This returns 1 because the first element **ab** contains **b**.

What I want is to return 1 only if it finds the whole word, and not a partial match.

So I want:

```
['ab', 'f', 'c'].indexOf('b') --> to return -1
['ab', 'f', 'c'].indexOf('ab') --> to return 1
```

Is it possible to do?

Comment: Strange. Normal `indexOf` on arrays shouldn't be returning `true` for that.

Comment: `['ab', 'f', 'c'].indexOf('b')` returns -1. Maybe you have redefined `Array.prototype.indexOf` ? (is it even possible ?)

Comment: `['ab', 'f', 'c'].indexOf('b') ` **does not** return 1, but -1, which means it didn't find anything. `indexOf` on an array doesn't search characters within strings and only performs `===` comparison between array elements and the searched value. What it does is exactly what you seem to be looking for.

Comment: I am so sorry, I overlooked the negative sign. I will close the question.